# django inline form validation

Tags: django, validation

For the Django Admin site, I write a custom form for a particular table, as say it named book.

I also write the validation method for book form and it works just fine.
Then I create the inline form of Books for Author.

Now my validations for Book form doesn't get call on inline form validation. I have to write them again in a inline formset clean function. I know it is accpetable, but I don't want to repeat.

So is there any way to apply my form validation on inline formset?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use mixin if you don't want to repeat

Comment: No multiple inheritance is language feature.